# How to display a function's definition in TreeForm?

Tags: functions, output-formatting, symbolic, trees

I want to use TreeForm to analyse functions. I come up with two methods to do it. The first one is preferred, but it doesn't work as expected. The second one is just a workaround. I don't know why the first one doesn't work.

To simplify the question, the function only has one definition.

In:

```
(*The function to be processed*)
REPLDStartedQ[] := 
 Module[{host = $host, port = $port, socket, result}, 
  socket = SocketConnect[host <> ":" <> ToString@port] // Quiet;
  result = 
   Switch[Head[socket], SocketObject, True, Symbol, False, _, False];
  If[result, Close[socket], False];
  result]

(*Method 1*)
(*When it works, it is the preferred way to go*)
(*Unexpected result*)
expr = (Definition@REPLDStartedQ // ToString) //
    StringSplit[#, ":=", 2] & // Last
expr // ToExpression // TreeForm

(*Method 2*)
(*It works, however I have to copy and paste the code to analyse it*)
(*Expected result*)
Module[{host = $host, port = $port, socket, result}, 
   socket = SocketConnect[host <> ":" <> ToString@port] // Quiet;
   result = 
    Switch[Head[socket], SocketObject, True, Symbol, False, _, 
     False];
   If[result, Close[socket], False];
   result] // Defer // TreeForm
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: How about `TreeForm[DownValues[yourFunction]]` ?

Comment: Thanks! I have tested a couple of functions. It works like a charm.:)

Comment: Although @Shadowray gave you a better solution to answer the "why" question, your code fails because `ToString` followed by `ToExpression` is not a robust operation.  In miniature: ``Hold[foo <> ":" <> bar] // ToString // ToExpression``.  Using `InputForm` fixes this particular case, i.e. ``ToString[Hold[foo <> ":" <> bar], InputForm] // ToExpression`` but even then this will not always give you back your original expression, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not an answer. Shadowray and Mr.Wizard answered the question in comments. To reply their comments, I have to write some code. It's too long and it can't be displayed in a comment properly.

ToExpression has some problems even I use ToString[#,InputForm]& beforehand. If the input is a string but not an expression, I still have to convert string to expression. I think I have found a way to do it,

In:

```
Clear[REPLDStartedQ];
expr = "REPLDStartedQ[] := Module[{host = $host, port = $port, \
socket, result}, socket = Quiet[SocketConnect[StringJoin[host, \":\", \
ToString[port]]]]; result = Switch[Head[socket], SocketObject, True, \
Symbol, False, _, False]; If[result, Close[socket], False]; result]";

expr // StringToStream // Read  
TreeForm@DownValues@REPLDStartedQ
```

Out:
[image: Mathematica graphics]